# An inner widget tree cannot be bigger than a page: A Widget cannot be drawn partially on one page and the remaining on another page: It's insecable

Tags: flutter, pdf, printing, pdf-generation, dart-pdf

In this **Multipage class** https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/MultiPage-class.html it is clearly mention an inner widget tree cannot be bigger than a page: *A Widget cannot be drawn partially on one page and the remaining on another page: It's insecable.*

I want to generate the views using this [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) plugin.

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import '../utils/page_data.dart';

makeTemplate3(pw.Document doc, pw.PageTheme pageTheme, PageData pageData,
    pw.MemoryImage profileImagee) {
  List<LineItems> _product = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int pos = i + 1;
    _product.add(
      LineItems(
        id: '$pos',
        name: 'Product',
        price: '100$i',
        quantity: '200$i',
        total: 'Total Sum: ' + (i * 200).toString(),
        desc:
            'Test widget $i: An inner widget tree cannot be bigger than a page: A Widget cannot be drawn partially on one page and the remaining on another page: Its insecable. A small set of Widget can automatically span over multiple pages, and can be used as a direct child of the build method: Flex, Partition, Table, Wrap, GridView, and Column.',
      ),
    );
  }

  doc.addPage(
    pw.MultiPage(
        pageTheme: pageTheme,
        build: (pw.Context context) => <pw.Widget>[
              _headerLayout(),
              // ignore: sdk_version_ui_as_code
              for (int i = 0; i < _product.length; i++)
                _productLayout(_product[i]),
            ]),
  );

  return doc;
}

_headerLayout() {
  return new pw.Container(
      padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      height: 80.0,
      color: PdfColors.blue,
      child: pw.Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          pw.Container(
            child: pw.Text(
              'Header',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));
}

_productLayout(LineItems item) {
  return new pw.Container(
      margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: pw.Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <pw.Widget>[
          pw.Column(crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            pw.Container(
              padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: pw.Text(
                item.name.toString() + ' - ID: ' + item.id.toString(),
                style:
                    pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            pw.Container(
              padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              child: pw.Text(
                  'Qty: ' +
                      item.quantity.toString() +
                      ' x Cost: £' +
                      item.price,
                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16)),
            ),
            pw.Container(
                padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                child: pw.Text(
                  '£' + item.total.toString(),
                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 14),
                )),
            pw.Text('Description: ' + item.desc,
                style: pw.TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16)),
            getSubItemList()
          ]),
        ],
      ));
}

pw.Widget getSubItemList() {
  List<pw.Container> list = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    list.add(
      pw.Container(
          child: pw.Text(
              'Sub Product: $i                         Total Sum:   $i-475',
              style: pw.TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16))),
    );
  }

  return pw.Container(
      padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(20), child: pw.Column(children: list));
}

class LineItems {
  String total, price, quantity, name, id, desc;
  LineItems(
      {this.total, this.price, this.quantity, this.name, this.id, this.desc});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complicated layout. All you need to do is flatten every block down to the MultiPage children.

Try this:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp('Printing Demo'));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp(this.title, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
        body: PdfPreview(
          build: (format) => _generatePdf(format, title),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format, String title) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();

    List<LineItems> _product = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      int pos = i + 1;
      _product.add(
        LineItems(
          id: '$pos',
          name: 'Product',
          price: '100$i',
          quantity: '200$i',
          total: 'Total Sum: ' + (i * 200).toString(),
          desc:
              'Test widget $i: An inner widget tree cannot be bigger than a page: A Widget cannot be drawn partially on one page and the remaining on another page: Its insecable. A small set of Widget can automatically span over multiple pages, and can be used as a direct child of the build method: Flex, Partition, Table, Wrap, GridView, and Column.',
        ),
      );
    }

    pdf.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: format,
        header: _headerLayout,
        footer: (pw.Context context) {
          return pw.Container(
              alignment: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
              margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
              child: pw.Text(
                  'Page ${context.pageNumber} of ${context.pagesCount}',
                  style: pw.Theme.of(context)
                      .defaultTextStyle
                      .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
        },
        build: (pw.Context context) => <pw.Widget>[
          for (int i = 0; i < _product.length; i++)
            ..._productLayout(_product[i]),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return pdf.save();
  }
}

pw.Widget _headerLayout(pw.Context context) {
  return pw.Container(
    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    height: 80.0,
    color: PdfColors.blue,
    child: pw.Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        pw.Container(
          child: pw.Text(
            'Header',
            style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Iterable<pw.Widget> _productLayout(LineItems item) sync* {
  yield pw.Container(
    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: pw.Text(
      item.name.toString() + ' - ID: ' + item.id.toString(),
      style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
    ),
  );
  yield pw.Container(
    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
    child: pw.Text(
      'Qty: ' + item.quantity.toString() + ' x Cost: £' + item.price,
      style: pw.TextStyle(
        fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
    ),
  );
  yield pw.Container(
    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
    child: pw.Text(
      '£' + item.total.toString(),
      style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 14),
    ),
  );
  yield pw.Container(
    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
    child: pw.Text(
      'Description: ' + item.desc,
      style: pw.TextStyle(
        fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
    ),
  );
  yield pw.SizedBox(height: 20);
  yield* getSubItemList();
  yield pw.SizedBox(height: 20);
}

Iterable<pw.Widget> getSubItemList() sync* {
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    yield pw.Container(
      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 20),
      child: pw.Text(
        'Sub Product: $i                         Total Sum:   $i-475',
        style: pw.TextStyle(
          fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.normal,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LineItems {
  String total, price, quantity, name, id, desc;
  LineItems({
    required this.total,
    required this.price,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.name,
    required this.id,
    required this.desc,
  });
}
```

Comment: It's working in this simple case. But when the child have the dynamic content to it's heading. How can we resolve that?

Comment: What kind of content?

Comment: Dynamic content that uses a new container widget with it's own list childs.